# params.require is preventing account creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to create an account, I get an error that the request failed with status code 422. This happens when I use `params.require`, but when I just use `params.permit` it works but still says

> unpermitted parameter

I have checked and the params are going through. Another problem I have is that I get

> password cannot be blank

when trying to create an account with `params.require`. I am using `has_secure_password` with `bcrypt`.

The only validations I have:

```
validates :username, presence: true, confirmation: {case_sensitive: false}, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 6..30}
validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true
```

Here is my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]

def create
    # byebug
    user = User.create!(user_params)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render json: user, status: :created
end

def show
    render json: @current_user, include: :animes
end

def update
    user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if user.update(user_params)
        render json: user, status: :ok
    else
        render json: user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :bio, :avatar, :email)
end

end
```

Here is a pic of the error!!!!! [image]

Here is all the code for my form on the front end:

```
 <Form.Group className="mb-2">
                    <Form.Label className="signup-form-headers">Username</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="username" value={formData.username} name="username" onChange={handleInput} placeholder="Enter Username" />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-2" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Label className="signup-form-headers">Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" value={formData.password} name="password" onChange={handleInput} placeholder="Password" autoComplete="on"/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPasswordConfirmation">
                    <Form.Label className="signup-form-headers">Confirm Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" value={formData.password_confirmation} name="password_confirmation" onChange={handleInput} placeholder="Confirm your password" autoComplete="on"/>
                </Form.Group>

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username:"",
    password:"",
    password_confirmation:""
})
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])
const history = useHistory()

function handleInput(e) {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
        if (formData.password != formData.password_confirmation) {
            setErrors(["Password and Password confirmation do not match"])
            return
        }
        await axios.post('/signup', formData)
        setUserIsLoggedIn(true)
        setFormData({
            username:"",
            password:"",
            password_confirmation:""
        })
        history.push("/")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error:", error)
        console.log("error data:", error.response.data.errors)
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors)
    }
}
```

What is preventing the account creation?

Comment: Looks like your form is not nested correctly. `username`, `password`, and `password_confirmation` should be nested in the `user` hash too. How does your form look like?

Comment: show me html.erb file

Answer (score 2):

Your params are not nested correctly as @spickermann said. Check that your form fields are correctly nested.

Username is nested and on the root level, password and confirmation are only on the root level.

When you use `require(:user).permit`, then only the username is present inside `"user"` and you get a validation error from your password field being blank.

When you use just `permit` without `require`, then the root level attributes are taken and `"user"` will be unpermitted and give a warning.